# Android - library module's interface method is not called in app module

Tags: android, picasso

I am using [Android Image Slider](https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidImageSlider) library for showing images on a slider. However, some images are not loading because backend requires authentication. So I need a listener for not loading images.

This is library: inside abstract BaseSliderView class, there is ImageLoadListener interface. I am setting listener using setOnImageLoadListener method.

```
public abstract class BaseSliderView {

    .....

    private ImageLoadListener mLoadListener;

    .....

    protected void bindEventAndShow(final View v, ImageView targetImageView){
        ....

        rq.into(targetImageView,new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {
                if(v.findViewById(R.id.loading_bar) != null){
                    v.findViewById(R.id.loading_bar).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onError() {
                if(mLoadListener != null){
                    mLoadListener.onEnd(false,me);
                }

                if(v.findViewById(R.id.loading_bar) != null){
                    v.findViewById(R.id.loading_bar).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
            }
        });
   }

    /**
     * set a listener to get a message , if load error.
     * @param l
     */
    public void setOnImageLoadListener(ImageLoadListener l){
        mLoadListener = l;
    }

    .....

    public interface ImageLoadListener{
        void onStart(BaseSliderView target);
        void onEnd(boolean result,BaseSliderView target);
    }

    .....

}
```

I checked, when image is not loaded, interface onEnd method is called in library module.

[image]

But on app module, onEnd method is not called even in library module it is called.

[image]

Why is this happening? Should not onEnd method be called in app module? How to solve this problem?

Comment: did you look at your AndroidMonitor to check the errors?
Try  `Log.i("Start")` instead of `MyLog.log("start")`;

Comment: It looks like it was hit somehow. Is `mLoadListener` an instance of your anonymous class?

Comment: yes, I checked AndroidMonitor to check errors - no log. onEnd method is not called at all.

Comment: @tynn, mLoadListener is an instance of interface which is inside abstract class where I got a problem

Answer (score 1):

I could solve this problem using greenrobot's EventBus library. First of all, I have added library dependency to library build.gradle file:

```
compile 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'
```

Created class for event:

```
public class ImageLoadErrorEvent {

    String url;
    ImageView imageView;

    public ImageLoadErrorEvent(String url, ImageView imageView) {
        this.url = url;
        this.imageView = imageView;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public ImageView getImageView() {
        return imageView;
    }

}
```

Posted on BaseSliderView class:

```
    @Override
    public void onError() {
        if(mLoadListener != null){
            mLoadListener.onEnd(false,me);
            EventBus.getDefault().post(new ImageLoadErrorEvent(mUrl, targetImageView));
        }

        if(v.findViewById(R.id.loading_bar) != null){
            v.findViewById(R.id.loading_bar).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    }
```

In Activity, inside onCreate method, registered EventBus:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_user);

    EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
```

Then created onMessageEvent:

```
@Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
public void onMessageEvent(ImageLoadErrorEvent event) {
    MyToast.show("Error");
}
```

Yay, now it is working!